# Jsfiddle code not working in localhost wamp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have implemented validation for fundtransfer in jsfiddle.
it works fine in jsfiddle but not working in localhost.
i am using wamp.

here is my jsfiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/BzdfN/31/

but when i am implementing this in localhost.its not working.

my html code is

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="validate.js"></script>
<title> Infy Bank Fund Transfer Entry Page </title>
</head>
<body>
<table class="layout" border="0" width="90%" align="center">
<form name="addcust" method ="POST" action ="http://localhost:8080/myapp/jsp/AddCustomerJSP.jsp">
    <td colspan="2">
    <table border="0" width="70%" align="center">
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2">
    <div class="heading2">Infy Bank</div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center" colspan="2"><p class="heading3">Fund transfer</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Payers account no<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="text10" id="text10" size="25" />
<div width="100%" id="equal"><a href="#" class="button button-green"></a></div>
    </td>
</tr>
<!--<tr>
    <td>Payees account no<span class="mandatory">*</span></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" value=2008 maxlength="25">   
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Amount<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" Value=500 name="state" maxlength="25"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Description<span class="mandatory">*</span></td><td><input type="text" name="pin" value=self maxlength="6"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span class="mandatory">*mandatory field</span></td>
    <td><input type="submit" name="AccSubmit" value="Submit" onClick="return validatebal();">
        <input type="reset" name="res" value="Reset"></td>
</tr>-->
</form>
</table>
<p align="right"><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

and my validate.js is

```
 $("#text10").keyup(function(){
        $("#text10").blur();
        $("#text10").focus();
});
$("#text10").change(function(){
var name = $('#text10').val();
         var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;   
         var specialChars = "<>@!#$%^&*()_+[]{}?:;|'\"\\,./~`-=";



    if (name == "" || name == " " )
        {
             $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("please enter account number");

        }


    else if(name.match(numbers))
    {
               $("#equal").hide();
             $("#equal a").html("correct account number");   //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
    }

    else if(name.match(specialChars))
    {
               $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("correct account number");   //  alert('All Boxes have elements.');
    }
  else 
        {
             $("#equal").show();
             $("#equal a").html("please check your account number  correctly");

        }

});
```

So guys can you what i am doing wrong.
please help

Comment: 'not working' without any more info is not something we can help with.

Comment: i have check this with firebug also but by firebug also i have not find the error.

Comment: Maybe this link help you out: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

start your `jQuery` with:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    .../ and end with:

});
```

maybe this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

In jsfFiddle your code is executed on the `onload` event.

But with including `validate.js` in the `head` the content of the script is execute  right at the place where you placed `<script src="validate.js"></script>`. So your jQuery selectors don't find any elements, because they are not in the DOM at the time the script is executed.

You have different possibilities.

1. Wrap the content of your `validate.js` into `jQuery(function() { /*your code of validate.js **/ })`
2. Another possibility is to place `<script src="validate.js"></script>` at the end of your document instead placing it in the head.
3. You can use delegated events like `$(document).on("keyup","#text10", function() { /* .... */ });`  that way it does not matter if `#text10` is in the DOM at this time.

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `validate.js` code in `jQuery` ready function as follows should solve the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// validate.js code

});
```